# Custom notification closes message boxes

Tags: vb.net

I have a custom notification form setup however my code below closes any messages boxes if they are open (opened from another form). These message boxes are often question boxes.

```
Private Sub DoneNotification_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
   FadeInTimer.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub FadeInTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FadeInTimer.Tick
    Dim opacityFade As Single
    For opacityFade = 0 To 0.8 Step 0.01
        Me.Opacity = opacityFade
        Me.Refresh()
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
    Next opacityFade

    FadeInTimer.Enabled = False
    WaitTimer.Enabled = True
End Sub

Public Sub FadeOutTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FadeOutTimer.Tick
    Me.Opacity -= 0.06
    If Me.Opacity = 0 Then
        Me.Dispose()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub WaitTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles WaitTimer.Tick

    WaitTimer.Enabled = False
    FadeOutTimer.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

I have tried me.close:

```
Public Sub FadeOutTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FadeOutTimer.Tick
    'This will decrement the opacity.
    Me.Opacity -= 0.06
    'Now that the form is at zero opacity we must 'dispose' of the form.
    If Me.Opacity = 0 Then
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

also tried this:

```
Public Shared Sub FadeOutTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FadeOutTimer.Tick
    'This will decrement the opacity.
    DoneNotification.Opacity -= 0.06
    'Now that the form is at zero opacity we must 'dispose' of the form.
    If DoneNotification.Opacity = 0 Then
        DoneNotification.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How do I stop it closing open message boxes when the notification closes.

Comment: There is no distinction between Dispose() and Close().  Dialogs like MessageBox always have an owner window, one they stay on top of and help the user switch back to.  Winforms doesn't force you to pick an owner window, it can usually find one by itself.  It uses the currently active window.  But at the risk that it is the wrong one, like the one you are fading.  Close the owner and the dialog is gonzo as well.

Comment: The snippet doesn't identify the bug, no MessageBox.Show() calls, but clearly you'll need to delay fading out until the message box is closed by the user.  The WaitTimer.Enabled = True statement needs to be moved.

Comment: How / when / in what part of code do you load/show notification form(s)?

Comment: It is activated from another form,

Comment: How would i detect if a message box is open?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved this one by putting my notification in another thread.